# Leveling up in solo-play?

Tags: payday-2

I prefer solo play, and I'm asking this question mostly as a follow-up to my previous question: [Crime.NET Offline](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/163885/crime-net-offline-play).

As many have pointed out in the my previous question, my main problem arises from being low-level and preferring to play solo. Does anyone have any tips, tricks, mission lists that would be capable by a lv ~20 character? Preferably stealth?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Couldn't comment. So heres a short.
Using the Mastermind skill tree, you can get more XP off missions. There is a basic skill called Dominator, this will make low levels easier and less chance of alarm.
Doing jobs in different orders on PC(Xbox & PS3 don't have this) will get you more XP and repeating them over and over gives you less if not none. Still get the cash and cards.
Jewelery store, Nightclub, also Ukranian job are easy by yourself if your a stealther.

Comment: Ever since they made answering pagers when dominating mandatory, Dominator has lost a bit of utility, honestly. It's nice to be able to tell SWAT to put their gun down for a second so I can shoot them though.

Comment: Nice to know. Haven't checked yet on PC. Console versions are still in it's beginnings.

Comment: If you think you are good enough with stealth, you could always do Deathwish Shadowraid. It nets a lot of EXP and Money...